# rails - is there a way to capture an entire POST's params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to capture an entire posts params, store it in the DB in one field (text), and then later get at each individual param? Possible? Any example you can show? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is something like the following. I didn't include all of the Sendgrid params since there are so many and you will know what I mean with a few:

```
class SendgridMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :attachments
  ...
end

class SendgridMessagesController < ApplicationController
   def create
     SendgridMessage.create(:to => params[:to], :from => params[:from], :attachments => params[:attachments])
   end
end
```

Sendgrid will send a POST to /sendgrid_messages with the params, and your object will be created with all of the correct fields (you will need to add some to the example) and serialized attachments like you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the entire params hash (or any other object)

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :params
  …
end

class SomeModelsController < Applicationcontroller
  def some_action
    SomeModel.create(:params => params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
request.raw_post
```

is what you're looking for?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post